# looping two columns when their time is close to each other by 30 sec

Tags: python

I have two columns in a dataframe named [Timeline and Start] and their type is a timestamp.

I want to write a function that can set a threshold value = 30 seconds, and if the time in the start column is close to any value in the time of the Timeline column by the threshold value, this value from the start column will be **moved** under the Timeline column.

For example,
insert 00:58:26 under 00:11:27 in the same start column if they have the difference in time of the threshold value.

[image]

Comment: Please include a [MRE] with example data and expected output. Your own efforts to solve your question are expected to be visible in the question as well.